# NetSim Error : No license for product (-1)

Tags: command-line, network-programming, simulation

NetSim Error : No license for product (-1)
When I run NetSim simulator, Simulation does not commence.
      "No license for product (-1)" 
             [image]
is displayed in the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetSim v7 works based on the client-server architecture. When NetSim runs in the client machine, it will check for the license in the same machine, first. If license is not available in the same machine, then "No license for product (-1)" will be displayed in the command prompt and the server machine will be checked for the availability of license. If no license is available in the server machine also, then again "No license for product (-1)" will be displayed in the command prompt.
So, if "No license for product(-1)" is displayed in the command prompt two times, then check in the NetSim license server to know about the availability of license and adjust the number of current users of NetSim, in order to get the license.